# Getting null error after fetching data from local db

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am having a db with few profile information, I would like to load them in my dashboard after the login. here is my code in my dashboard screen.

```
class __DashboardPageState extends State<_DashboardPage> {

  UserClass userObject;
  var db;

  __DashboardPageState(){
    getUserObj();
  }
  void getUserObj() async{
    db = new DatabaseHelper();
    userObject = await db.fetchUsers();
  }


//-----------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getUserObj();

    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: new Text(
        "Welcome Back, "+ userObject.firstname,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: "Yorkten_ConMed",
          fontSize: 14,
          color: Color(0xffffffff),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

> The getter 'firstname' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried
>   calling: firstname

Getting this as error in my console and screen is showing error like attached. I know due to async it is not initialized before the screen getting drawn. but i dont know how to pull and load the data in my widget from db apart from this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the visibility of widget while the data is being loaded.

- Instead of constructor use [AfterLayout](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout) to load your data, once data is fetched from DB, do `setState`.
- You can show loader while the data is being loaded by using package [screen_loader](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_loader).
- You need to handle the possible null values

Like in your case it is obvious `userObject` will be null initially so when you are using `userObject`'s properties use like this: `userObject?.firstname ?? '-'`, here if either `userObject` or `firstname` is null then return `'-'`

Comment: Actually i want to reload the screen once the data is pulled from local db, i am not getting any clue to identify when the data is loaded bcos of using Future

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a FutureBuilder instead of a StatefulWidget page, so you can reload ONLY the item that changes, and doing so you save a few resources and fix your problem as well. In the future use the DB call `db.fetchUsers()` and use something like this:

```
     if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
           child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                );
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                                );
                              } 
             else {
                  //return your Widget here
                  }
```

You can validate later when `snapshot.hasData` if this data is null and react accordingly like `snapshot.data.firstname ?? 'No name'`